# How to take dynamic variable in postgresql function.?

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql query to copy data from csv file and insert that data into another table..the query works fine but i want that query to be put into a function so that i can use this function in my c# application.
Here is the query which works fine...

```
copy emp_temp from 'd:\\temp.csv' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' CSV QUOTE AS '"';
```

here emp_temp is the table and temp.csv is my file.

but

when i am using the above function like

```
create or replace function CopyToTable(file_path text,table_name text) returns void as
    $body$
        begin
            copy quote_ident(table_name) from  file_path  WITH DELIMITER AS ',' CSV QUOTE AS '"';
        end;
    $body$
    language plpgsql volatile
```

It shows error like

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "file_path"...
```

From some of the suggestions i also tried using dynamic sql

```
create or replace function CopyToTable(file_path text,table_name text) returns void as
    $body$
        begin
            execute 'copy quote_ident(' || table_name || ')' || ' from  ' ||
            file_path || 'WITH DELIMITER AS ' || ',' || ' CSV QUOTE AS ' || '"';
        end;
    $body$
    language plpgsql volatile
```

The function compiles successfully...but when i am giving parameters by running the function

```
select * from CopyToTable('d:\\temp.csv','emp_temp')
```

it shows error..

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "d"
LINE 1: copy quote_ident(emp_temp) from  d:\\temp.csvWITH DELIMITER ...
                                     ^
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but i already have used this but still error

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "*I already have used this*" - there is no dynamic SQL in your question.

Comment: execute 'copy quote_ident(' || table_name || ')' || ' from  ' ||
   file_path || 'WITH DELIMITER AS ' || ',' || ' CSV QUOTE AS ' || '"';

Comment: Update the question with the new syntax and error message.

Comment: Related question: [COPY with dynamic file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019508/copy-with-dynamic-file-name/16021835)