# Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, alter-table

I tried to use a function to set the n_distinct value for a table. The code is as follows:

```
create temporary table _temp
(
  id integer
);

create function pg_temp.setdistinct(_cnt real)
returns void as $$
begin
  alter table _temp
    alter column id set (n_distinct=_cnt);
end
$$ language plpgsql;

select pg_temp.setdistinct(1000);
```

Yet receive the following errors:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid value for floating point option "n_distinct": _cnt
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "alter table _temp
>          alter column id set (n_distinct=_cnt)"
> PL/pgSQL function pg_temp_3.setdistinct(real) line 3 at SQL statement
> ```

The issue can be bypassed using an `EXECUTE` statement, but I wonder why we can't use a variable in this particular query. Is there any particular rule I overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. The manual explains in the chapter [***Variable Substitution***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST):

> Variable substitution currently works only in `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`,
> and `DELETE` commands, because the main SQL engine allows query
> parameters only in these commands. To use a non-constant name or value
> in other statement types (generically called utility statements), you
> must construct the utility statement as a string and `EXECUTE` it.

You *cannot* parameterize the value in a dynamic statement with `EXECUTE` either because, [quoting the chapter ***Executing Dynamic Commands***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in
> `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands. In other statement types
> (generically called utility statements), you must insert values
> textually even if they are just data values.

The ***only option*** in a plpgsql function is to concatenate the value into the command string. You might use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT), but for the simple example, plain concatenation is safe and easy::

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.setdistinct(_cnt real)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE _temp ALTER COLUMN id SET (n_distinct=' || _cnt || ')';
END
$$;
```

The schema-qualification `pg_temp.` makes it an (undocumented!) "temporary" function, mirroring the question.
The manual about [`n_distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html).