# How to use a subquery as a database name in a DDL command?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, dynamic-sql, identifier

I am wondering if it's possible to use the result of a subquery as database name in a PostgreSQL (9.5.1) DDL statement.

For example, I wanted to alter the current database with something like:

```
ALTER DATABASE (SELECT current_database()) SET a_var TO 'a_value';
```

If I run this, an error occurs:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ALTER DATABASE (SELECT current_database()) SET ...
```

What's the correct way to use the sub-query (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format($f$ALTER DATABASE %I SET x.a_var TO 'a_value'$f$, current_database());
END
$do$;
```

Using `format()` to escape the db name safely while being at it.

BTW, to unset:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db RESET x.a_var;
```

To see the current setting:

```
SELECT current_setting('x.a_var');
```

(The DB default is not active before you start a new session.)

Related:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025308/error-when-setting-n-distinct-using-a-plpgsql-variable/36025963#36025963)