# Missing FROM-clause entry for table »rowtype«

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, partitioning, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.4

I am currently writing a function in the plpgsql language to create partitions which will hold sensor data for each month (one partition for one month and sensor). I am stuck with this error:

> ```
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table »curr_sensor«
> SQL state: 42P01
> Context: SQL-Query »CREATE TABLE sensor_1_201609 (CHECK (timestamp >= date(curr_sensor.timestamp) AND timestamp < (date(curr_sensor.timestamp) + interval '1 month'))) INHERITS (sensor_fake_data)«
> PL/pgSQL-Function create_partition_per_sensor_and_month() Line 20 at EXECUTE
> ```

The function looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_per_sensor_and_month() RETURNS text as
$BODY$
-- declare variables
DECLARE
    loop_count integer := 0;
    curr_sensor sensor_fake_data%rowtype;
    curr_partition_limit timestamp;
    partition_table_name text;
    partition_index_timestamp_name text;
    partition_index_id_name text;
-- begin with the for loop...loop over every sensor and partition based on sensor and the timestamp
BEGIN                                                                   --replace mumber with variable
    FOR curr_sensor IN SELECT * FROM sensor_fake_data WHERE sensor_id = 1 ORDER BY timestamp ASC
    LOOP
        IF (loop_count = 0 OR curr_sensor.timestamp > curr_partition_limit) THEN
            curr_partition_limit := curr_sensor.timestamp + interval '1 month';
            partition_table_name := 'sensor_' || cast(curr_sensor.sensor_id as text) || '_' || to_char(date(curr_sensor.timestamp), 'YYYYMM');
            partition_index_timestamp_name := 'index_timestamp_' || cast(curr_sensor.sensor_id as text) || date(curr_sensor.timestamp);
            partition_index_id_name := 'index_id_' || cast(curr_sensor.sensor_id as text) || date(curr_sensor.timestamp);
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition_table_name || ' (CHECK (timestamp >= date(curr_sensor.timestamp) ' || 
                     'AND timestamp < (date(curr_sensor.timestamp) + interval ' || '''1 month''' || '))) ' ||
                     'INHERITS (sensor_fake_data)';
            -- add index to the new table
            EXECUTE format('CREATE INDEX %I ON %I (timestamp)', partition_index_timestamp_name, partition_table_name);
            EXECUTE format('CREATE INDEX %I ON %I (sensor_id)', partition_index_id_name, partition_table_name);
            EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES(curr_sensor.*)', partition_table_name);
        ELSE
            EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES(curr_sensor.*)', partition_table_name);
        END IF;
        loop_count := loop_count + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
```

I dont understand why there is missing a FROM-Clause. In general I don't understand the Error since I am just trying to create a table (at line 20) and to set some check constraints?

Comment: There is no declaration for `curr_sensor`in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. The error is correct...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto so I have to store `curr_sensor` under a variable in order to use it in a SQL-Query which is being run with the `EXECUTE` keyword?

Comment: There are no variables declared in the statement of the `EXECUTE` statement.

Comment: Also, i do not think `INHERITS` is what you need here... I would use `LIKE`, as per docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: maybe you meant `' (CHECK (timestamp >= date(curr_sensor.timestamp) '` to be `' (CHECK (timestamp >= date($$'||curr_sensor.timestamp||'$$) '` and same for `'AND timestamp < (date(curr_sensor.timestamp) + interval '`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curr_sensor` is a row / record variable inside the plpgsql function (the required declaration `LANGUAGE plpgsql` is missing btw).

But your `EXECUTE` tries to create a table with a `CHECK` constraint referring to a *table* called `curr_sensor`, which obviously does not exists. Nor should it.

Instead, pass the properly quoted (!) *value* of the column `curr_sensor.timestamp` to concatenate the correct DDL statement. It seems odd you wouldn't use `format()` for this while you have it in your function for other, simpler commands. Use it to clean this up, and quote properly:

```
...
   EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I (CHECK (timestamp >= %L AND timestamp < %L))
                   INHERITS (sensor_fake_data)'
                 , partition_table_name
                 , curr_sensor.timestamp::date
                 , (curr_sensor.timestamp + interval '1 month')::date);
...
```

There may be more problems, I did not look much further.

Related:

- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025308/error-when-setting-n-distinct-using-a-plpgsql-variable/36025963#36025963)

Either way, consider upgrading to **Postgres 10** (currently RC), which ships with shiny new [**declarative partitioning**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html#ddl-partitioning-declarative) to replace partitioning based on inheritance.

I posted some sample code with links and explanation in this related answer on dba.SE recently:

- [Better database for “keep always the 5 latest entries per ID and delete older”?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186085/3684)

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I changed the `EXECUTE` query by using the built-in `format()` function and now it works. A very simple and dumb mistake, but I was confused by the error messages and therefore I couldn't figure out what exactly the problem was.