# How do I evaluate a cursor loop variable as a table name?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

```
FOR _r IN curs1 LOOP
    ALTER TABLE QUOTE_IDENT(_r.table_name) ALTER COLUMN company_uuid SET NOT NULL; 
END LOOP;
```

I am trying to convert the table name to an identifier so I can use it dynamically.

The error is: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Values* can be parameterized for the core DML statements `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.

But ***identifiers*** (or syntax elements) cannot be parameterized anywhere in SQL. In PL/pgSQL you can use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` like [Anton suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69122084/939860). I.e., concatenate the whole command as *string* and then execute. See:

- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025308/error-when-setting-n-distinct-using-a-plpgsql-variable/36025963#36025963)

Optionally use `format()` for convenience:

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I ALTER COLUMN company_uuid SET NOT NULL', _r.table_name);
```

With the `%I` specifier for identifiers, unless `_r.table_name` is already quoted properly. See:

- [Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variables-in-format-for-execute/22675836#22675836)

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly it is invalid to use functions in the command. You may use dynamic sql instead.

```
EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || QUOTE_IDENT(_r.table_name) || ' ALTER COLUMN company_uuid SET NOT NULL;';
```