# how to call and send parameter to postgres procedure

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, psql

i have postgres procedure like this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateTransactionsFromBackups(date text);
        CREATE PROCEDURE updateTransactionsFromBackups(date text)
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
        AS $$
        declare
        path text;
        BEGIN
        path := '/var/www/old_backup_' || date || '.sql';
        COPY old_transactions(id,user_id)
            FROM  path NULL as 'NULL' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
        END;
        $$;
```

and when i try call procedure like

```
CALL updateTransactionsFromBackups('2023-03-13'::text);
```

iget this message :

```
No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: you are creating a procedure named `updatetransactionsfrombackup` but your CALL statement uses `updatetransactionsfrombackupS`

Comment: I wonder why you define the procedure with a parameter of type ```text``` and call it with a value of type ```varchar```. Eventhough, I think PostgreSQL feels sufficiently smart to call the function anyways and apply some internal cast. But you might try to get your types aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your function call should just work as given. Demo:
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8YdkDVeU)

Did you use double-quotes in either the function definition or the call? Like `"updateTransactionsFromBackups"`. That would explain the mismatch. My standing advice: use legal, lower case identifiers to begin with, then you don't need to quote, and nothing breaks if you do. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

But there is more: What you are trying to do does not work. The `COPY` command does not support variable substitution. You need dynamic SQL. See:

- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025308/error-when-setting-n-distinct-using-a-plpgsql-variable/36025963#36025963)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_transactions_from_backups(_date date)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
   _path text := '/var/www/old_backup_' || to_char(_date, 'YYYY_MM_DD') || '.sql';
BEGIN
   IF _path IS NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Input cannot be NULL!';
   END IF;

   EXECUTE format(
      $$COPY old_transactions(id, user_id)
        FROM %L NULL AS 'NULL' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER$$
    , _path);
END
$proc$;
```

Call:

```
CALL update_transactions_from_backups('2023-03-13');
```

Note the use of dollar-quotes. See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Pass the date as actual type `date`. This way you are safe from SQL injection, as only valid dates are accepted. Format the date with `to_char()` any way you need it. And use `format()` with the format specifier `%L` to concatenate the command string with the right amount of single quotes easily.

Note that this form of `COPY` requires the privileges of a superuser the `pg_read_server_files` role.